# Service Fabric - How to repair a failing stateful application

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have a stateful service that configures state backups for the primary replica on RunAsync using an Azure storage account.

The other day someone inadvertently deleted the storage account being used for backups. On our next deployment, the services began throwing errors as they initialize due to this 404 error response.

I have noticed that during a deployment fabric apparently shuffles around the old version of the service spinning up new primaries as needed to free up the vm it is upgrading. If the old version of the code fails to instantiate by throwing an exception, the upgrade process will fail causing a rollback.

My problem is, once I create a new storage account, I am still left seemingly no way to bring the existing services back to healthy states. My existing services are using Storage account urls with AccountKeys that no longer exists in azure. Attempts to upgrade fail because the old service instances can’t instantiate due to now bad configuration.

Are there any ways to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be to use an [unmonitored manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade#upgrade-modes) upgrade to force through the change that would point the service to the new storage account.

However, this puts a lot of management overhead on you, particularly if there are many other services, since you need to be careful to perform all safety and functionality checks manually so as not to regress anything.

The recommend solution is to use the ServiceTypeHealthPolicyMap described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-parameters) to "mask out" the unhealthy service (since you expect it to be unhealthy during the upgrade). You may also need to adjust some of the other upgrade parameters depending on the exact situation.

A third recommendation, or maybe something to improve in the future, would be to make the upgrade to change the account information a configuration only upgrade. This would ensure that SF tries to change the config in-place without restarting the services (by default), which would prevent the existing services from failing over during the upgrade and encountering issues. This is demonstrated in [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-data-aggregation#upgrade-patterns).

Comment: What would happen if I try a config only upgrade on service that are already in a failure loop? would they get the new config?

Comment: Yes but the overall upgrade is the same as any other upgrade - gated on the health and safety checks. So you need to modify the health policy map either way. I mentioned it because you said that the error was introduced on failover, and that's a way to avoid failovers (in the future).

Comment: ok thanks, the health policy map looks promising, I just can't decide how often to use it. On the one hand, would be nice to just make that a part of the CI pipeline fabric upgrade script, and in general this would ensure upgrades succeed. But I am wary of masking errors when there is in fact a real issue, so maybe will keep that option just for a manual intervention.